# subvalue additivity

Tags: self-study

How would you show that whenever  additively represents an agent’s preferences, then so does any function ′ that differs from  only by the choice of zero and unit.

If we assume that  additively represents an agent’s preferences, so that for some subvalue functions 1, 2, ... , ,
(⟨1, 2, ... ,  ⟩) = 1(1) + 2(2) + ... + ().

and assume ′ differs from  only by a different choice of unit and zero, which means that there are numbers  > 0 and  such that ′(⟨1, 2, ... ,  ⟩) =  ⋅ (⟨1, 2, ... ,  ⟩)+.

How do we show that that there are subvalue functions1′,2′,...,′ such that
′(⟨1, 2, ... ,  ⟩) = 1′(1) + 2′(2) + ... + ′().

Answer (score 4):

Let $V(a_1,...,a_n)$ be an additive separable utility.

$$V(a_1,...,a_n)=\sum_iv_i(a_i)$$

Let $\alpha>0$ and $\beta\in \mathbb{R}$ be given. Let $U(a_1,..,a_n):=\alpha V(a_1,..,a_n)+\beta$. $U$ also represents the preferences. I claim that $U(a_1,..,a_n)$ also has an additive representation

$$U(a_1,...,a_n)=\sum_i\left(\alpha v_i(a_i)+\frac{\beta}{n}\right)$$

Define $u_i(a_i)=\alpha v_i(a_i)+\frac{\beta}{n}$

$$U(a_1,...,a_n)=\sum_{i}u_i(a_i)$$

Therefore, $U$ also is additively separable

Comment: are we able to show 1′,2′,...,′ such that ′(⟨1, 2, ... ,  ⟩) = 1′(1) + 2′(2) + ... + ′()

Comment: Yes. I simply used U instead of V'. In your original question, take $V_i'=xV_i+\frac{y}{n}$